# How can I connect netlify-cms with self-hosted gotrue and git-gateway?

Tags: netlify, netlify-cms

The title is pretty self-explanatory I think.
Repos can be found here:

- https://github.com/netlify/netlify-cms/
- https://github.com/netlify/git-gateway
- https://github.com/netlify/gotrue

I try to not use netlify's commercial solution and handle this only with their open source software.

Comment: I wasn't able to add tags for git-gateway and gotrue as it needs 1500 points of reputation...

Answer (score 1):

This is the best example I'm aware of, and where I generally point folks to as an example. Setting up these projects is currently non-trivial.

https://github.com/hfte/netlify-cms-with-selfhosted-gotrue-and-git-gateway

Comment: That github link is going to a 404 now. Does anyone have other examples? Much appreciated!